# Cannot GET /about.html express/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, mean-stack

I am trying to use express and body-parser libraries to create a simple node server. It is not supporting the static files as I stated below in the example. What is the mistake which i am making? Kindly help me.

[image: About.html]

**server.js**

```
 var express = require("express");
var bodyParser =require("body-parser");
var app = express();
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function()
{
console.log("Server started on Port 3000"); 
});
```

[image: Error]

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blog post",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Package.josn for node server",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```

I have updated my server.js as per the recommendation.

**server.js (updated)**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser =require("body-parser");
var app = express();
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function()
{
console.log("Server started on Port 3000"); 
});
```

Worked Version
**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser =require("body-parser");
var app = express();
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function()
{
console.log("Server started on Port 3000"); 
});
```

Comment: Please don't change the code you originally had in your question to now incorporate things people have recommended.  That obscures the original question you asked and invalidates answers that were provided based on the original question.  You can ADD new info to your question if you've incorporated some advice, but are now still stuck.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my question as you suggested. Kindly help me to overcome the problem. As a senior member, it would be great if you can recommend StackOverflow to allow coding formatting in the comments area. It is very difficult to add code in the comments area.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jfriend00. It worked fine after i remove the public.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make files public before using them as static files from `expressjs` server as below -

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

This serves your `public` directory as static directory. Put all your static files in `public` directory and serve.

If you want to serve from multiple directories you can do following -

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('files'));
```

More info - http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I have updated my server.js as your recommended(see my above question), but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The only route you show is this:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res)
```

That's for the URL: `localhost:3000/`.

But, the URL in your image is `localhost:3000/about.html` which you do not have a route for.  So, you can either make a route for that particular URL or you can use `express.static()` to automatically serve files from a particular directory.

Express does not automatically serve ANY files (unlike some other web servers) so any file that you want served must have a route that handles it (either individually or a route that handles many files).

Comment: I have changed server.js code as below, but still getting the same error. var express = require("express");
var bodyParser =require("body-parser");
var app = express();
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function()
{
console.log("Server started on Port 3000"); 
});

Comment: @user5555457 - multiline code is completely unreadable in comments.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to add new code to the end of your question (don't change prior stuff) and then leave a comment to tell people that you've added some new info to your question.  DO NOT remove what you originally asked a question about because that invalidates all the answers you have so far which is not fair to people who provided you good info that you have already used.  If your app is still not working, then you can ADD new info to the question that explains where you are currently stuck.

Comment: @user5555457 - You added `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`, but your `index.html` doesn't look like it is in a `public` sub-directory below your script directory.

Comment: You should not use express.static on your script directory as it will serve your node.js scripts too.  Move your public files to a public subdir by themselves and point express.static at that.

Comment: Got it. I will do..Thanks a ton for your continuous help.